# Push in an a new array and filtering redundant objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I receive from an ajax call  an array of object and some of them are the same, so i want want to push only unique objects in an another array.

```
receivedArray = [{name:italy, id:67},{name:italy, id:67},{name:france, id:89}]
```

and i want that :

```
myArray = [{name:italy, id:67},{name:france, id:89}]
```

how can i do that ?

Comment: did you tried anything, or searched stackoverflow properly before posting this question?

Comment: yes i searched of course sorry if my question is redundant.  As each elemnt in an object the solutuons i saw didn't work.

Comment: what is your parameter for uniqueness of the objects? is it only name, or id or both ?

Comment: it would be the id.

Answer (score 1):

Use `reduce` & `findIndex` method. `findIndex` will return the index of the object if the accumulator array already have an object where the id matches. If `index` is -1 which mean that accumulator array does not have that object.In that case add the array to the accumulator array

```js
let receivedArray = [{
  name: 'italy',
  id: 67
}, {
  name: 'italy',
  id: 67
}, {
  name: 'france',
  id: 89
}]


let myArray = receivedArray.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  let findIndex = acc.findIndex(function(item) {
    return item.id === curr.id;
  })
  if (findIndex === -1) {
    acc.push(curr)
  }

  return acc;
}, [])
console.log(myArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily solved in es6:

```js
const receivedArray = [{name:'italy', id:67},{name:'italy', id:67},{name:'france', id:89}]
const newArr = receivedArray.filter((item, index, self) =>
  index === self.findIndex((i) => (
    i.id === item.id && i.name === item.name
  ))
)
console.log(newArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` and `Set` to do something like this perhaps:

```js
receivedArray = [{name:'italy', id:67},{name:'italy', id:67},{name:'france', id:89}]

mySet = new Set();

myArray = receivedArray.filter(e => {
  if (mySet.has(e['id'])) {
    return false;
  } else {
    mySet.add(e['id']);
    return true;
  }
})

console.log(myArray);
```